# Mysqli update query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

So I'm trying to build a kind of update email function, and the part that should put it into the db looks like this

```
<?php $emailfrom = $_POST['emailfrom'];
        $emailto = $_POST['emailto'];
        $query = sprintf('UPDATE `users` SET `email`="%s" WHERE `email`="%s"`',
        mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $emailfrom),
    mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $emailto));
        mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

The problem is that the row don't update... And I need help in knowing why, as I'm not so well experienced with mysql, used other dbs mainly earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got syntax error in your query.

```
                                                                     \/
$query = sprintf('UPDATE `users` SET `email`= "%s" WHERE `email`= "%s"`',
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $emailfrom),
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $emailto));
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Also, you probably want to change emails from emailFrom to emailTo, now you are doing it the other way around. After edit:

```
$query = sprintf('UPDATE `users` SET `email`= "%s" WHERE `email`= "%s"`',
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $emailto),
mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $emailfrom));
mysqli_query($db, $query);
```

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work, and what exactly is the error with `email`

Comment: You have additional ` in the end of the string. 
Change `email`= "%s"` to `email`= "%s"

Comment: Now you got the syntax right. I edited my answer, if I'm correct you are updating your row the other way around. Otherwise I don't have any idea left why your query isn't working, since syntax is okay, the code you posted also. Try debugging with error_reporting.

Comment: That made it! Thousands of thanks, I'm feeling pretty stupid now, it was so obvious when you said It...

Comment: Haha, don't worry, common mistake made by tired people :) Glad you got it.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer will work, but a prepared statement would be much safer

```
$query="UPDATE `users` SET `email`= ? WHERE `email`= ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$_POST['emailfrom'],$_POST['emailto']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

With a prepared statement you don't have to worry about escaping your variables to prevent SQL injection.